# How can I change the Google Pagedown Editor to use font awesome icons?

Tags: javascript, pagedown

We are using the pagedown editor with an AngularJS directive. This is I believe the same one as used on stack overflow:

```
angular.module("ui.pagedown", [])
.directive("pagedownEditor", function ($compile, $timeout, $window, $q) {
    var nextId = 0;
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    Markdown.Extra.init(converter, mdExtraOptions);

    converter.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
        return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
            return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
        });
    });

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            content: "=",
            showPreview: "@",
            help: "&",
            insertImage: "&"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var editorUniqueId;

            if (attrs.id == null) {
                editorUniqueId = nextId++;
            } else {
                editorUniqueId = attrs.id;
            }

            // just hide the preview, we still need it for "onPreviewRefresh" hook
            var previewHiddenStyle = scope.showPreview == "false" ? "display: none;" : "";

            var newElement = $compile(
                '<div>' +
                    '<div class="wmd-panel">' +
                            '<div id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '"></div>' +
                            '<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '" ng-model="content"></textarea>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="wmd-preview-' + editorUniqueId + '" class="pagedown-preview wmd-panel wmd-preview" style="' + previewHiddenStyle + '"></div>' +
                '</div>')(scope);

            // html() doesn't work
            element.append(newElement);

            var help = angular.isFunction(scope.help) ? scope.help : function () {
                // redirect to the guide by default
                $window.open("http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax", "_blank");
            };

            var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "-" + editorUniqueId, {
                handler: help
            });

            var editorElement = angular.element(document.getElementById("wmd-input-" + editorUniqueId));

            //add watch for content
            if(scope.showPreview != "false") {
                scope.$watch('content', function () {
                    editor.refreshPreview();
                });
            }
            editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function() {
                // wire up changes caused by user interaction with the pagedown controls
                // and do within $apply
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.content = editorElement.val();
                });
            });

            if (angular.isFunction(scope.insertImage)) {
                editor.hooks.set("insertImageDialog", function(callback) {
                    // expect it to return a promise or a url string
                    var result = scope.insertImage();

                    // Note that you cannot call the callback directly from the hook; you have to wait for the current scope to be exited.
                    // https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown#insertImageDialog
                    $timeout(function() {
                        if (!result) {
                            // must be null to indicate failure
                            callback(null);
                        } else {
                            // safe way to handle either string or promise
                            $q.when(result).then(
                                function success(imgUrl) {
                                    callback(imgUrl);
                                },
                                function error(reason) {
                                    callback(null);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    });

                    return true;
                });
            }

            editor.run();
        }
    }
})
.directive("pagedownViewer", function ($compile, $sce) {
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    Markdown.Extra.init(converter, mdExtraOptions);

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            content: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var unwatch;
            var run = function run() {
                // stop continuing and watching if scope or the content is unreachable
                if (!scope || (scope.content == undefined || scope.content == null) && unwatch) {
                    unwatch();
                    return;
                }

                scope.sanitizedContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(converter.makeHtml(scope.content));
            };

            unwatch = scope.$watch("content", run);

            run();

            var newElementHtml = "<pre ng-bind-html='sanitizedContent'></pre>";
            var newElement = $compile(newElementHtml)(scope);

            element.append(newElement);
        }
    }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1Vxo5UfYpHQdjhWatimU?p=preview

We would like to change this to use the font-awesome icon set instead of use icons but we are not sure how to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I would need to do to make it use font-awesome instead of the default icons.

Thanks,

Comment: To be clear, you would like a solution to replace the top row of icons, i.e. "Bold", "Italic", etc with your own font icons? Can you include the font awesome icon in the plunkr as well as the icons you would like to replace it with. This will most likely have to be done by modifying the underlying Markdown.editor.js file. It is currently using a .png row and overlaying buttons on top.

Comment: @Adam - Yes this is exactly what I would like to do. I am not sure how easy it is for me to include the font-awesome items as I am not really familiar with using plunkr. I think any solution to this question that used a best guess at the icons would be good. For example use of the icon-bold for Bold and icon-italic for Italic.  Thanks

Comment: Currently the button bar rendering in the Pagedown editor is not customizable, so in order to properly use the font-awesome you have to fork the Pagedown editor code and apply the modifications there. If you don't plan to use your custom PageDown you can hack in the buttons, but some things won't work like the styling when they are disabled. I've put together a quick example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dg5pgiLpZ5K2Owkpk8pR?p=preview. If this workaround is enough for you I can explain the solution in a proper answer.

Comment: @nemesv - Thanks for taking the time to come up with the example. I think forking the PageDown would be good for us.  I assume we would just need to be very clear of what to change in the future so that a year ahead we could still keep up with any changes to PageDown and not miss out on bug fixes. Just to clarify,  the workaround you have. Was that from a fork of PageDown you modified.  If so then that would be just what we are looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Currently the PageDown editor does not support any customization for the button bar rendering.

So you are left with three options:

- you just create your own buttons image file and use that for the icons. However in this case you are losing the benefits of using font-awesome.
- you fork and add the necessary modification to `Markdown.Editor.js`
- you change the generated HTML after the Editor is rendered and removing the old buttons and adding the new ones, but some features won't work, more on that later

### Solution 1: create your custom button image

The PageDown editor uses one sprite image to store all the buttons and their hover and disabled state. So you can modify that to have your custom buttons.

Then you just need to change your CSS to use the icons (here I've used the SO editor buttons):

```
.wmd-button > span {
    background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/wmd-buttons.svg");
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLivjhXk9rbeGDuvQ9H3?p=preview)

### Solution 2: fork the `Markdown.Editor.js`:

Essentially you have to change two methods:

- the `makeButton` function which generates a `span` and applies the background positioning (the PageDown editor uses a big image to contain all the button and their states). Here you just need to add the FA classes
- the `setupButton` which deals with the event wiring, the hover effect and the disabled state. Here you need to remove the enabled state handling or optional the hover handling because this can be also done in your `angular-pagedown.css`

So the code of the `makeButton` will look like:

```
var makeButton = function (id, title, XShift, textOp, faclass) {
        var button = document.createElement("li");
        button.className = "wmd-button";
        button.style.left = xPosition + "px";
        xPosition += 25;
        var buttonImage = document.createElement("span");
        buttonImage.className = "fa " + faclass;
        button.id = id + postfix;
        button.appendChild(buttonImage);
        button.title = title;
        button.XShift = XShift;
        if (textOp)
            button.textOp = textOp;
        setupButton(button, true);
        buttonRow.appendChild(button);
        return button;
    };
```

And the `setupButton` would look like this:

```
    function setupButton(button, isEnabled) {

        var image = button.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
        if (isEnabled) {
            image.style.color = "#000000"
            if (!button.isHelp) {
                button.onclick = function () {
                    doClick(this);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            image.style.color = "#c5c5c5"
            button.onmouseover = button.onmouseout = button.onclick = function () { };
        }
    }
```

Finally you have to modify the calling site of the `makeButton` to include the required font-awesome classes when the buttons are created:

```
buttons.bold = makeButton("wmd-bold-button", getString("bold"), "0px", bindCommand("doBold"), "fa-bold");
//...
```

On the CSS side you need to add the hover effect and remove the background:

```
.wmd-button > span {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wmd-button > span:hover {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLjlh1ngzsljuNQUjDlN?p=preview)

### Solution 3: change the generated HTML:

This solution does not require to change the Markdown.Editor but the enable/disable state handling won't work.

Basically you have to add the font-awesome classes to the generated `span`: in your angular directive after the `editor.run();`:

```
 var icons = [
          {md: "wmd-bold-button", fa: "fa-bold"},
          //...
          ]

        icons.forEach(function(i) {
          var e = angular.element(document.getElementById(i.md + "-" + editorUniqueId));
          e.find("span").addClass("fa "+ i.fa);
        });
```

In this case you also need to change the CSS a little bit:

```
.wmd-button > span {
     width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.wmd-button > span:hover {
    background: #99cafa;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dg5pgiLpZ5K2Owkpk8pR?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [font-awesome version](https://github.com/micrum/awesome-pagedown) of PageDown library